# Why back button is working after signout in django server?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using django server and i have multiple business function in python views module.
From views function i am generating multiple page and in each page signout button is there.
after clicking on the signout it will redirect signin page.
when i am hitting the pertichular url it will hit a views function and i am checking session which was created on signin.

the problem is that browser store cache data and after signout it will generate the old  page from local cache. i want to prevent it.

I was puting this 2 line before each views function then cache file is deleted from local machine and old page is not comming but i am getting some issue:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
```

The issue is that after sign out if i login then if i press back button then its trying to find out the old page that is already deleted from the cache thats why i am getting

```
Document Expired and This document is no longer available error
```

How can i fixed it ?

should i remove the cache data in front end using javascript or backend?

thanks in advance for proper answer.

Comment: Please post the http headers you receive from the page you don't want to cache.